# Is there a way to get all the results on my code in 1 row instead of multiple rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to get results on 1 row instead of multiple rows.

I am new to SQL and not sure what else to do.

```
SELECT
  I.D1NAME,
  S.MEMBER_NBR,
  s.SHARE_NBR
FROM ID.MonthEnd_DL_Load_Dates EOM
JOIN SHARE S ON
  EOM.month_end_date = S.DL_LOAD_DATE AND
  COALESCE(S.CLOSED,0) = 0 AND
  DATEDIFF(DAY,S.LAST_CUST_CONT_DATE,MONTH_END_DATE) > 365
JOIN MEMBERSHIPPARTICIPANT MP ON
  S.DL_LOAD_DATE = MP.DL_LOAD_DATE AND
  S.MEMBER_NBR = MP.MEMBER_NBR
JOIN INDIVIDUAL I ON
  MP.DL_LOAD_DATE = I.DL_LOAD_DATE AND
  MP.INDIVIDUAL_ID = I.INDIVIDUAL_ID
WHERE EOM.sequence = 1
```

I am getting:

```
Rob 1234 1
Rob 1234 2
```

I would like to get:

```
Rob 1234 1,2
```

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you using?

Comment: I think it is 2012

Comment: Thanks for the edit, a_horse_with_no_name.  I was having a hard time getting this typed on here.  My apologies.

Comment: Have you tried [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2012) ?

Comment: No, I have not.  I will have to research how to use it with my current query,.  My current query gives me all the results that I need...I would just like to have condensed into 1 row per name/member number.

Comment: One of your join statements is finding more than one matching row on the joined table. I would suggest querying all columns with SELECT * to try to identify the culprit table. Once you identify it, It could just be a matter of adding an additional clause to that table's join conditions. GL.

Answer (score 0):

FOR SQL SERVER 2008 - 2016

This workaround uses XML PATH and STUFF in order to aggregate multiple rows of a single variable into one row of concatenated values. This solution mimics STRING_AGG from SQL SERVER 2017.

I will demonstrate using the AdventureWorks database and the following query:

```sql
SELECT SOH.SalesOrderID
      ,STUFF
        (
            (
                SELECT ', ' + CAST(SOD.ProductID AS VARCHAR(20)) AS [text()]
                FROM AdventureWorks2016.Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS SOD
                WHERE SOH.SalesOrderID = SOD.SalesOrderID
                ORDER BY SOD.SalesOrderDetailID
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, NULL
        ) AS ProductIDs
 FROM AdventureWorks2016.Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SOH
```

Example Output:

```
SalesOrderID    ProductIDs
51176    796, 872
51177    970, 708
51178    779, 871, 870
51179    795, 933, 922, 879
51180    793, 872, 870, 707, 714
51181    792, 922, 933, 707
```

XML PATH concatenates together the by returning values as text nodes. STUFF eliminates the leading comma. The SELECT statement will concatenate together the collected text nodes and delimit the results by using the following line:

```sql
SELECT ', ' + CAST(SOD.ProductID AS VARCHAR(20)) AS [text()]
```

PITFALL:
Be sure to cast your SHARE_NBR as a VARCHAR (or NVARCHAR) as it will not work with numeric data types since XML PATH is returning text type data.

Comment: Thank you very much!!  I will try this first thing in the morning.  I REALLY appreciate your help!!

Comment: And in my original "I would like to get" above, this will give me that?  Where my results will be, as an example,   Rob 1234 1,2,5,10??

Comment: STRING_AGG is not a built-in function in SQL Server 12.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I will edit my post with a workaround for SQL Server 2012.

Comment: I just got home and got the message, so I am not sure.  I did find a work around with PIVOT then CONCAT.  Here is what I have gotten.

Comment: Well it won't let me put it in for some reason.  The last issue I am having is that with the CONCAT (which worked great), I am getting results like this.

Comment: John Smith     12345     1,2,3,4,5, , , , , , , , ,     I am wanting to get rid of the extra spaces and commas, when I don't need them.  I can't figure out how to COALESCE the SELECT statement with the CONCAT function.  I have to COALESCE because some people might have 1 result, some might have 3 and then some might have 10 results.  Any ideas on this?

Comment: SELECT D1NAME, MEMBER_NBR,
  CONCAT([SHARE_1],', ',[SHARE_2],', ',[SHARE_3],', ',[SHARE_4],', ',[SHARE_5],', ',[SHARE_6],', ',
              [SHARE_7],', ',[SHARE_8],', ',[SHARE_9],', ',[SHARE_10],', ',[SHARE_11], ', ',[SHARE_12]) as [DORMANT SHARES]

Comment: `SELECT D1NAME, MEMBER_NBR,  
STUFF(  
COALESCE(', ' + CAST([SHARE_1]  AS VARCHAR(30)), '') +  
COALESCE(', ' + CAST([SHARE_2]  AS VARCHAR(30)), '') +  
COALESCE(', ' + CAST([SHARE_3]  AS VARCHAR(30)), ''),  
1,2,'') AS DORMANT_SHARES`